Migrate to supported version of Google Play Billing Library 6+ Error
I'm a unity Mobile game developer. Because of the Google Play Billing Library Migration I updated my In-app purchase package manager to 4.12.2 and the latest external dependency manager also. In the IAPAndroidDependencies file I can see the billing client 6.2.1. I didn't changed any of my purchasing script. After I updated all those I submitted and still I get the error message of the Google Play Billing error. What should I do to solve the issue?
I updated the unity In-app Purchasing package.
I updated the ExternalDependencyManager also

I've faсed the same issue and struggled to find the answer.
After hours of researching (google and my own project files) I've found this line in my file Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version" android:value="5.0.0" tools:replace="android:value" />

Removing the line fixes the issue.
I don't know why I put it here earlier (maybe some unity billing integration guide required that step) but it seems the line confuses Google Play Console what exactly billingclient version is referenced in my project.
Hope it can help in your case too.
